# WSO2 error I/O error: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I was trying with a usecase as mentioned below

Need to define a REST API , make calll to SOAP webservice. A simple usecase . But I get below error . Is there anything wrong in my configuration ? I am able to executeS SOAP service from SOAPUI without any issues .

please see  Error stack trace below.

```
[2020-04-24 10:45:38,611] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - I/O error: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingIOSession$LoggingByteChannel.write(LoggingIOSession.java:218)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flush(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:167)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractContentEncoder.flushToChannel(AbstractContentEncoder.java:103)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.ChunkEncoder.write(ChunkEncoder.java:129)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.Pipe.consume(Pipe.java:159)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceResponse.write(SourceResponse.java:279)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler.outputReady(SourceHandler.java:376)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpServerConnection.produceOutputWire(LoggingNHttpServerConnection.java:246)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpServerConnection.produceOutput(LoggingNHttpServerConnection.java:129)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.MultiListenerServerIODispatch.onOutputReady(MultiListenerServerIODispatch.java:94)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.MultiListenerServerIODispatch.onOutputReady(MultiListenerServerIODispatch.java:32)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.outputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:143)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.writable(BaseIOReactor.java:180)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:342)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Looks like the connection is getting terminated by Firewall or something. Can you disable your firewall settings and check?

Comment: Hi thanks for response  , To give more information on this , I get this error only while using API end point . Also , when i keep it running mode for sometime (without executing interface),  using WSO2 EI studio  7.0.2   I get this error in studio console.  But when i tried with file end point with same setup i didnt find any such error ,